# What is destinationURI or URI itself?

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I have extended a cropview library CropIwa and it is very good. It satisfies me well. The problem is when saving the crop image it asks about the destinationURI and I dont know how to get it.

My plan is to save it to database or if best firebase storage.

SOrry for the grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this `Uri` indicates where the cropped image should be written to after cropping.

For example, you could create a `File` object pointing to where you want the image to be saved, and then use `Uri.fromFile()` to get a `Uri` pointing to that location. Pass that `Uri` to the `CropIwaSaveConfig.Builder` constructor.

Comment: it is too vague to read. First, i want to thank you for answering my questions. May you show me how it is done please? Like saving it to gallery